# This code is not executable for IEEE ACCESS document Class \documentclass{ieeeaccess}. Generates error like this: 1.23}?

Tags: tables, longtable, xtable

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
 \usepackage{algorithmic}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed FA-HELF model and the benchmark}
\label{tab:Y_Forecast}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  S[table-format=1.4]
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Proposed} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{SDPSO-ELM \\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
            & {\thead{F-RBF-CNN\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                & {\thead{SSA-SVM-CS\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                     & {\thead{FA-HELF \\ MAPE\\(\%)}} \\
\midrule
    Jan & 2.22 & 1.67 & 1.55 & 0.414\\


\midrule
Avg.& 2.12 & 1.79 & 1.44 & 0.410\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
 \EOD
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Which command do you use?

Comment: @albert. It gives error like this. illegal character in the array arg

Comment: Please add the exact error in the question so there is also a reference to where it happens etc.

Comment: As the document class is not standard, you should probably also add a link to where to get this class.

Comment: Plus this `mwe`  will never compile as there is no `\begin{document}`. Changing to the `article` class, moving `textcomp` to after `kpfonts` (as Kp loads textcomp on its own), adding `\begin{document}` and removing the unknown `\EOD` and the example compiles just fine,

Comment: @ daleif. I have used begin{document} and removed \EOD. But the problem still exist. KIndly help

Comment: Please cite the error you get and provide a link for this class. It does not come with latex so I cannot test it.

Comment: @daleif @Werner's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/525181/latex-generate-error-in-ieee-access-template-in-figure-algorithm-and-table indicates `\EOD` is part of the class, like the figure environment.

Comment: @daleif There's a latex template at http://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/wp-content/uploads/Access-Template.zip

Comment: Again no problems here at my end. Please update your MWE with `\begin{document}` in the right spot and either remove `textcomp` or move it after `kpfonts`. Then your MWE works fine at my end using TeXLive 2019. If it still does not work at your end please update your question with the exact error you get, or even better the entire log file. From what you have given us so far we cannot help any further

Comment: @GhulamHafeez: You need to use `\Table` instead of `\begin{table}`...`\end{table}`. Have you read through the example `access.tex` document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MWE

- are missed package `siunitx, \booktabs` and `makecell`, consequently this cause your error(s)
- the package `amssymb` contain/load `amsmath` package, so it is not necessary load it (again)
- you load `algorithmic` twice
- in table you define 6 columns, but use only 5 (accordingly is necessary to correct `\cmidrule`)
- number in columns are maximal three decimal digits, so there is not sense to require space for four, even more, since all numbers  has the same units (percents) it is sensible to round all numbers to two decimal digits.

After correcting your MWE with aforementioned flaws, your MWE can be:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}    % <---
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}            % <---
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell} % <---

\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed FA-HELF model and the benchmark}
\label{tab:Y_Forecast}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Proposed} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{SDPSO-ELM \\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
            & {\thead{F-RBF-CNN\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                & {\thead{SSA-SVM-CS\\ MAPE \\(\%)}}
                     & {\thead{FA-HELF \\ MAPE\\(\%)}} \\
    \midrule
Jan     & 2.22  & 1.67  & 1.55  & 0.414 \\
Avg.    & 2.12  & 1.79  & 1.44  & 0.410 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\EOD
\end{document}
```

works fine and gives expected result:

[image]

Addendum:
Background of your table is unknown to me, but see if the following modifying  doesn't change its meaning:

[image]

Code for above table is:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Evaluation of the proposed FA-HELF model and the benchmark}
\label{tab:Y_Forecast}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
    \sisetup{round-mode=places,
             round-precision=2,
             table-format=1.2,
             }
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  *{4}{S} }
    \toprule
 & \multicolumn{4}{c}{MAPE of the proposed methods} \\
    \cmidrule{2-5}
\thead{Months}
        & {\thead{SDPSO-ELM\\ (\%)}}
            & {\thead{F-RBF-CNN \\ (\%)}}
                & {\thead{SSA-SVM-CS\\ (\%)}}
                     & {\thead{FA-HELF\\ (\%)}} \\
    \midrule
Jan     & 2.22  & 1.67  & 1.55  & 0.414 \\
Avg.    & 2.12  & 1.79  & 1.44  & 0.410 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
```